# php simplexml get object variable start with number

Tags: php, object, simplexml

When I parse an rss file with SimpleXMLElement, I get this object :

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#307 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(39) "http://workspace/wordpress/hello-world/"
}
```

$var->0 doesn't works.

I don't know how to do it :(

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It behaves like an array

```
echo $var[0];
```

In this case - when there's only one (child) element - you don't even have to use the index

```
echo $var;
```

Comment: $var[0] gives the same result. $var is a SimpleXMLElement. Thanks